# How to avoid filling in missing fields when updating a Hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, passwords

I'm developing an app with a user management system. There is a database table named `user` with the following columns:

```
| Column Name     | Column Type |
|-----------------|-------------|
| userId          | BIGINT      |
| email           | TEXT        |
| firstName       | TEXT        |
| lastName        | TEXT        |
| passwordDigest  | TEXT        |
| birthday        | DATE        |
| address         | TEXT        |
```

And there is a corresponding Hibernate entity called `User`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    private long userId;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String passwordDigest;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private String address;
}
```

However, the general user info (i.e. email, first name, last name, birthday, address) and password are getting updated in separate pages in my app. Specifically, there is a "Edit Your General Info" page for users to update their general info, and there is a separate "Update Your Password" page for users to update their passwords. Just like lots of other apps.

Therefore, the code for each pages will be:

```java
void updateUserGeneralInfo (User newUser) {
    User oldUser = userDao.getExistingUser(newUser.getUserId());
    newUser.setPasswordDigest(oldUser.getPasswordDigest());
    userDao.updateUser(newUser);
}

void updateUserPassword (long userId, String newPassword) {
    User oldUser = userDao.getExistingUser(userId);
    oldUser.setPasswordDigest(calculateDigest(newPassword)); // auto save to DB by Hibernate
}
```

The problem lies in `updateUserGeneralInfo()`. Since `newUser` is passed from GUI, it doesn't contain a `passwordDigest`. Therefore, directly calling `updateUser(newUser)` would wipe out the user's `passwordDigest` in the DB. To avoid that, it's necessary to retrieve the user's existing entity just to fill in the password digest, so that `updateUser(newUser)` won't affect the user's `passwordDigest`. This is kind of clunky and hard to maintain.

Assuming that I am allowed to re-design what the database table `user` and the Hibernate entity `User`. Is there any way to avoid retrieving the existing entity and filling in the field `passwordDigest` in `updateUserGeneralInfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DML statement to update only the attributes that you care about, but managed entities work this way. When a managed entity is attached to a persistence context, it is synchronized to the database.

Comment: Could you please show me how a DML statement can help me solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you only want to update the username for example then use `entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE User u SET u.username = :name WHERE u.id = :id").setParameter("id", userId).setParameter("name", username).executeUpdate()`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the DML statement example. However, it seems a bit tedious, especially when adding/modifying fields of `User`. What I am looking for is a way that the code is easy to maintain.

Comment: You could also use a tool like Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views which allows you to model this and create these more efficient DML statements behind the scenes for you: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#updatable-mappings-basic